# Insert binary threshold image (CV_8UC1) into a ROI of a coloured mat (CV_8UC4)?

Tags: opencv, mat, roi, binary-image

I've got a sequence of images of type CV_8UC4. It is of HD size 1280x720.
I'm executing the bgfg segmentation (MOG2 specifically) on a ROI of the image.
After the algo finished I've got the binary image of the size of ROI and of
type CV_8UC1.
I want to insert this binary image back to the original big image. How can I  do
this?

Here's what I'm doing (the code is simplified for the sake of readability):

```
// cvImage is the big Mat coming from outside
cv::Mat roi(cvImage, cv::Rect(200, 200, 400, 400));
mog2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
cv::Mat fgMask;
mog2->apply(roi, fgMask); // Here the fgMask is the binary mat which corresponds to the roi size
```

So, how can insert the fgMask back to the original image?
Hwo to do this CV_8UC1 -> CV_8UC4 conversion only for the ROI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `fgMask` a 4 channel image:

```
Mat4b fgMask4ch;
cvtColor(fgMask, fgMask4ch, COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
```

and then copy this into the original `cvImage` at the correct position, given by `roi`:

```
fgMask4ch.copyTo(roi);
```